# Any other way to find palindrome other that using the abstract data type "STACK"?

Tags: stack, palindrome

i want to any other efficient way to find the palindrome of string other than using stack data structure. this is code i have written using stack operation.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package StringRevUsingStack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class StringReverseThroughStack {
    // private data members;
    private String InputStr;
    private String OutputStr;

    //Constructor
    public StringReverseThroughStack(String ip){
        InputStr = ip;
    }

    public String doReverse(){
        Stack theStack = new Stack(InputStr.length());
        String revStr;
        for(int i=0;i<InputStr.length();i++)
        {
            theStack.push(InputStr.charAt(i));
        }
        revStr="";
        while(!theStack.isEmpty()){
            revStr+=theStack.pop();
        }
        return revStr;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the String:");
        String ip=br.readLine();
        StringReverseThroughStack theStr = new StringReverseThroughStack(ip);
        String op=theStr.doReverse();
        if(ip.compareTo(op)==0)
            System.out.println("It is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println("It is a not palindrome");

    }

}
class Stack{
    private int maxSize;
    private char[] stackArray;
    private int Top;

    public Stack(int max){
        maxSize = max;
        stackArray = new char[maxSize];
        Top=-1;
    }
    public void push(char item){
        stackArray[++Top]=item;
    }

    public char pop(){
        return stackArray[Top--];
    }

    public char peek(){
        return stackArray[Top];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
   return (Top == -1);
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you considered? What options did you come up with?

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer` has a `reverse()` method. That should be all you need.

Comment: That just shifts the question ("is it possible to reverse a string without using a stack?"), although I'm positive the answer "yes".

Answer (score 0):

You could do this just with a simple for loop iterating over the string in reverse.

(Assuming java)

```
public String ReverseThisString(String inputStr) {
    String outputStr = new String();

    for(int i = inputStr.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        outputStr += String.valueOf(inputStr.charAt(i));
    }

    return outputStr;
}
```